# How do I read the last modified date of a file in a Zip archive using Node.js?

Tags: node.js, zip

I have a zip archive containing a single compressed file. I wish to extract said file and retain the *unzipped* file's last modified date.

Packages like [unzip](https://www.npmjs.com/package/unzip) create the uncompressed file in the moment losing the original last modified date.

How do I retain or even just read the unzipped file's original last modified date?

Comment: Ah. You can't, since once zipping it, it's effectively modified. You could store a txt file containing the modified date when the file is zipped in the first place and then just read it? (Also I edited your wording to make it more clear what you're asking).

Answer (score 0):

You can read the last modified date per file entry in the archive using the [yauzl](https://github.com/thejoshwolfe/yauzl) package as follows:

```
 pathZipFile = 'myArchive.zip';

 yauzl.open(
    pathZipFile,
    function (err, zipfile) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        zipfile.on(
            "entry",
            function (entry) {
                // directory file names end with '/'
                if (/\/$/.test(entry.fileName)) {return;}

                // Read the last date modified per archive entry
                console.log(entry.fileName, '-', entry.getLastModDate());
            }
        );
    }
 );
```